# Why TypeScirpt doesn't generated classes first?

Tags: typescript

Why TypeScript compiler generated from this code

```
var test = new Foo();

class Foo {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

this fail

```
var test = new Foo();

var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
})();
```

instead of this?

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
})();

var test = new Foo();
```

I can't imagine any reason, why classes not generated first...

Comment: Since TS defines class with an IIFE, the resulting Foo is a function expression and not a function declaration. If it were a declaration, then your code would work. It could be possible for TS to move all class operations to the top, but the real question is why you would write it in the failing order to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to see that this simple code is not correctly ordered.

However, it's nearly impossible to take *any* code and determine if it's correctly ordered or not. It's even more difficult than that to take *any* code and always generate a correct ordering. A correct ordering may very well not exist.

Even if this were solved on a per-file basis, there's nothing preventing you from messing up the order of `script` tags on a webpage and causing ordering problems that way.

Given all that, the compiler just has one simple rule about ordering: The code is emitted in the order you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not do any semantic ordering for your code.

Its the same as this block of code:

```
var b = x; 
x=123;
var x;
```